# combining diacritics

Tags: characters, combine

I'm trying to combine the diacritics `\d` and `\^`. For the letter e for example with the help of some kerning: `\^{\kern-.4em}{\d{e}}`. The result does not paste well here

Two problems. I should not have to resort to kerning. This approach also upsets spacing with adjacent characters. The `tipa` manual did not provide an obvious solution.

Comment: At least in my tests it looks better the other way round: `\d{\^{e}}`. (If you have lots of diacritics like this maybe you want to consider switching to a Unicode engine [LuaTeX or XeTeX]: With LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX the order in which you give the diacritics doesn't matter and you could even input the Unicode characters directly [if you like that sort of thing].)

Comment: @moewe -- Actually, the order of inputting multiple diacritics *does* matter if more than one is on the same end (top or bottom) of the base character -- order them with the one closest to the character on the output to be also closest in the input.  (Other than that, I agree with your suggestion.  And in this example, since one diacritic is above and one below, my caveat isn't relevant.)

Comment: Thank you. It did not occur to me that order could make a difference. The alternative order suggested works well. I avoid LuaTeX because I fear publishers won't know what to do with it.